Electron application with React, Vite and Typescript can't load preload script
I started my project using sandbox: false, which is a bad security practice. After noticing my mistake i changed to true, by doing that i got the following error:
VM4 sandbox_bundle:2 Unable to load preload script: C:\work\projectplace\project\out\preload\index.mjs
VM4 sandbox_bundle:2 
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at runPreloadScript (VM4 sandbox_bundle:2:83494)
    at VM4 sandbox_bundle:2:83813
    at VM4 sandbox_bundle:2:83968
    at ___electron_webpack_init__ (VM4 sandbox_bundle:2:83972)
    at VM4 sandbox_bundle:2:84095

I started to comment every single place of my index.ts (preload) and i discovered that for some reason, if i import something, let's say, contextBridge, and print that, the code break:
import { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } from 'electron'

console.log('Preload script loaded successfully.')

if (process.contextIsolated) {
  try {
    console.log('Context is isolated.')
    console.log(contextBridge)
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('------------------')
    console.error(error)
    console.log('------------------')
  }
} else {
  console.log('Context is not isolated.')

  // @ts-ignore (define in dts)
  // window.electron = electronAPI
  // // @ts-ignore (define in dts)
  // window.api = api
}


I am using the electron-vite(https://electron-vite.org/) package on this project.

As stated on Electron's documentation about ESM:

Sandboxed preload scripts can't use ESM imports
Sandboxed preload scripts are run as plain JavaScript without an ESM context. If you need to use external modules, we recommend using a bundler for your preload code. Loading the electron API is still done via require('electron').

If you don't use a bundler and want to keep sanboxing enabled, use require instead of import on the preload.

Thanks, you clarified this for me. So, because of some packages that i am using, i need to transpile everything to .mjs. Do you know if there is a way to only transpile the preload.ts to common js?

@CarlosEduardoRochaMiranda I don't know, it all depends on your config. I would say it's the matter of another question.
